# iPad 2 Wi-Fi/GPS Sensor

Tags: xcode, ipad, gps, wifi, sensors

I have a technical question for the iPad 2 Wi-Fi (or actually iPad in general).
I am creating a map based application and get the longitude and latitude to show to a user the accurate location, speed, course ...

In the end it should also work offline without Wi-Fi.
But if i switch off the WiFi i get no change in lat. and long. anymore.

I actually thought, that the iPad does not ***mainly*** use hot spots to get the actual position.

Or is it possible, that the GPS-Sensor is part of the Wi-Fi module?

Comment: I dont think you can achieve that. Because either you need internet connection or GPS enabled to get ur current Location

Comment: There is no 'GPS-Setting' in the iPad. You can switch location services: On (and that what i have) and there is the  Wi-Fi setting(like in the iPhone). If i switch Wi-Fi off, there is no localization available anymore. The question is if there is a GPS chip in it or not? !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The iPad 2 WiFi does not have assisted GPS (see spec [here](http://www.apple.com/ipad/specs/)). It will have some location services when connected to a WiFi network.